# I am not able to get text from textfield on popup. get ERROR "reason: 'text Field Index (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'"

Tags: iphone, xcode

The following code implemented but i am get error "reason: 'text Field Index (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'"

when popup function if fired i get popup

```
- (IBAction)popup:(id)sender{

    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post your message" message:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    UITextField *textField;
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    textField.frame = CGRectMake(15, 75, 255, 30);
    textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:20];
    textField.placeholder = @"Post your message";
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:textField];
    [alert show];


    //NSLog(@"%@",buttonIndex)

}
```

[image]

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    NSString *value=[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]text];
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if ([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0 ||
            [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil ||
            [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqual:@""] == FALSE)
        {
           NSLog(@" textbox value here => %@",value);
        }
        else
        {
             NSLog(@" text box was empty ");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@" Cancel is pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: check again if (buttonIndex == 0) button index is zero not 1.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: i want textbox value from popup not button value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue lies at this point `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0]`. Your textField is not at 0th position. if you `NSLog(@"%@",[alertView subviews]);` you can see your textfield is at last in array not at first position. So try to get textfield this way.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[alertView subviews]);
        UITextField *txtField = [[alertView subviews] lastObject];
        if ([txtField.text length] > 0 ||
            txtField.text != nil ||
            [txtField.text isEqual:@""] == FALSE)
        {
            NSLog(@" textbox value here => %@",txtField.text);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@" text box was empty ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@" Cancel is pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First just add this line in your code after create `UIAlertView`

```
[alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];// you can use also another style like... `UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput` or `UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput`
```

and then try this bellow logic..

```
//your other code
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
textField.tag = 111; // just add this line...
//your other code..
```

and then just replace this below method...

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   UITextField* myField = (UITextField*)[alertView viewWithTag:111];
   NSString *value = myField.text;
   if (buttonIndex == 1) {
      if ([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text length] > 0 ||
        [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text != nil ||
        [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqual:@""] == FALSE)
      {
           NSLog(@" textbox value here => %@",value);
      }
      else
      {
           NSLog(@" text box was empty ");
      }
    } else {
       NSLog(@" Cancel is pressed");
    }
}
```